# FrameLog and .Net Framework

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, logging

I was looking for some simple entity framework logging and I found out FrameLog. I see that its minimal EF version requirements is 5. But what about the .net framework version? Will FrameLog will be fully functional on EF 5 and .Net Framework 4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET framework version 4 or above is fine. See [here](https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/framelog/wiki/Requirements).